# Are there any benefit to join a party when fighting World Bosses

Tags: guild-wars-2

When I'm doing my daily World Boss tour, I see a lots of people always looking for a party to join. Beside the social aspect, is there any benefit to it that I'm not aware of ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number valid reasons to join a party, none of which make it absolutely necessary to do so. Being in a party never *directly* influences your loot (but see 2.)

#### 1. Protection against disconnects

When in a party, chances are you will be able to rejoin the same map instance as them after a disconnect.

#### 2. Easier tagging/event contribution

To get the full participation credit (the gold medal) for an event, or loot from a specific mob, you have to deal a specific amount of damage. This number is shared in a group, and makes it easier to get tag the mobs before they are killed.

This can be easily observed with the pre-boss champs at the Great Jungle Wurm or Moodnir Ulgoth, where it can be hard to get gold participation without a party.

#### 3. Boon/Buff Priority

Effects that affect a certain number of allies prioritize party members over non-party members, making it easier to buff up in a controlled manner.

---

However, IMO, the most common reason to join a party is "Monkey See, Monkey Do." If a new player sees someone do it, they usually assume that it's really important for something, without knowing why it makes sense. It's how I started doing it.

Comment: I think the Tequatl example is bad.  Unless Teq has changed recently, it's usually the case that people in the zerg don't party up, so that all of the boons distribute more evenly.  But Boon/Buff priority would certainly be a good reason to party up in more challenging areas like SW and soon to be HoT maps, that way your boons don't land on some random passerby derpin' around.  There's definitely a lot of 'monkey see, monkey do' in world boss trains though(where it only really matters for Ulgoth, Caledon's wurm, etc)

Comment: "This number is shared in a group, and makes it easier to get[sic] tag the mobs before they are killed." Do you have any official sources for that? I've never had problems getting gold participation solo there, but you could be right. +1 for your third point in any case, though I agree with @Ryan that Tea Kettle is probably a bad example.

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter That reason is the only reason I ever saw quoted in-game when I was new. These days, the disconnect protection is more of an issue, but tagging enemies was always the primary reason before. When dealing with a large zerg, if the damage you do is insignificant, you won't get loot. The exact threshold isn't clear, but can be observed now if you run with a large WvW zerg and only get a single non-crit hit on a Tower Lord while not in a party. It was also more obvious when the Queensdale train was active and slower, lower geared players would barely hit a Champion and get no loot.

Comment: I removed the Teq example, but I actually can't think of any others where it actually makes sense. As for the tagging, @AmosM.Carpenter the three Avatar of Blight champs (husks) just before the (single) Wurm can be hard to fully tag if you are alone and only melee.

Comment: @MrLemon: Which is why you won't find me going all-out melee at such events. ;-) If you're looking for a better example, though, how about the three-headed wurm? Doesn't seem to be done much anymore, but organised, balanced groups are usually required for a successful triple-decap-plus-kill. Or... Orr.

Answer (score 0):

Many GW2 players believe that being in a party gives you a better chance to get loot, especially at large events with many mobs. However, I don't think this has ever been officially confirmed by the devs, so the best you're going to find is "anecdotal evidence", for instance:

- https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/game/gw2/Loot-Solo-vs-Group
- https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/game/gw2/Being-in-a-party-means-better-loot-XP
- http://www.guildwars2guru.com/topic/78935-magic-find-and-party-loot-tables/
- http://www.guildwars2guru.com/topic/74151-is-there-any-benefit-to-creating-a-party/

From my own experience, I don't think the loot quality is any better or worse either way, but I suspect there may be a grain of truth to it in so far as tagging things (which determines *whether* you get loot, though not how good that loot is) while grouped is easier than when soloing, because (possibly) buffs that you give your teammates *may* count towards tagging an enemy you don't directly damage yourself. Note I'm being careful not to jump to conclusions, because this is of course also merely anecdotal.

Either way, those people looking to party up at events are most likely those who *believe*. If you think it's superstition or a placebo effect, don't bother grouping; it's up to you whether you want to believe. ("The loot is out there!")